# OpenSSL: how to encrypt/decrypt?

Tags: terminal, macintosh, encryption, openssl

In Debian, I'll encrypt a file or text:

```
$ echo test | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in - -pass pass:password -out /tmp/test.enc
```

Then move the file to macOS (Mojave) and attempt to decrypt:

```
$ openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in /tmp/test.enc -pass pass:password
bad decrypt
4426204780:error:06FFF064:digital envelope routines:CRYPTO_internal:bad decrypt:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.200.4/libressl-2.6/crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:533:
```

This `-d` command decrpyts properly in Debian but not macOS. Could someone shed some light on what's going on and how I can use openssl to encrypt/decrypt between the two operating systems?

Debian openssl version:

```
$ openssl version -v
OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018
```

macOS openssl version:

```
$ openssl version -v
LibreSSL 2.6.4
```

Comment: Just tested on Mojava (with a locally encrypted file): Decrypting using your command worked without problems.

Comment: No, you have to encrypt the file using Debian. Decrypting with Mojave works fine if the file was also encrypted with Mojave. I'm trying to get it working between different operating systems.

Comment: How do you transfer the file from Debian to macOS? Does it work if you encrypt on macOS and decrypt on Debian? Does it work if you use a different cipher?

Comment: Transfer using a USB or netcat or something. Encrypting with Mojave doesn't decrypt in Debian. But I just tried encrypting with Ubuntu (openssl v1.0.2g) and it decrypted in Mojave with errors. So maybe a temporary workaround there. Still, would like a Debian/Mojave solution. I'll try different ciphers now, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Okay, if you think the question will get more exposure there :(

Comment: also, i tried ~7 other ciphers, none worked

Comment: Try adding the `-a` argument to both the encryption and decryption steps.  That will base64 encode the output, which is a lot more resistant to "helpful" utilities that might convert CRs to CRLFs or the reverse.

Comment: I'm getting essentially the same result (except the error has different numbers) with a file encrypted on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS / OpenSSL 1.0.2g 1 Mar 2016, and transferred to macOS 10.13.6 / OpenSSL1.1.0e  16 Feb 2017, and vice versa. I've tested both with & without `-a`, transfers done via `scp`, and the shasums match so it's not getting corrupted in the transfer.

Comment: Is this just an experiment for a proof-of-concept, or are you planning on trying to encrypt actual important information with `enc`? Is OpenSSL 1.1.0h compatible with LibreSSL 2.6.4?

Comment: GordonDavisson, thanks for verifying the issue. @Xen2050, I did plan on encrypting sensitive information this way, would you advise against it?? Also, "Is OpenSSL 1.1.0h compatible with LibreSSL 2.6.4?" I think that's the question. How would I find out for sure?

Comment: From [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28247821/openssl-vs-gpg-for-encrypting-off-site-backups/28248800#28248800) OpenSSL's `enc` command uses a non-standard undocumented format, doesn't specify the encryption algorithm, "uses a custom key derivation function [that's] non-standard and not-well vetted construct (!) which relies on MD5 ... (!!); the "iteration count" is set by the enc command to 1 and cannot be changed (!!!!)." If you want well tested & documented & compatible encryption, just use GPG.